# Javax.constraint with Spring how to Validate if value is null or not blank?

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a POJO

```
class Body{
   LocalDate date;
}
```

and a Spring rest endpoint

```
@PostMapping(..)
public ResponseEntity<?>(@RequestBody @valid Body body){}
```

If i send JSON `{}` Everything should be fine as date can be null. But i want it to give validation error if date is blank, either `{"date":""}` or `{"date":" "}` should give validation error.

I already have created custom validator for Strings that does this, but LocalDate is not string and if it is given a blank value, it outputs as null. Is there a way for me to check, if date is null, it was also null in the JSON and not just a blank field?

Comment: No. As you are validating the `Body` not the incoming JSON. Those are 2 separate things which shouldn't be confused. If you want to influence the parsing of the JSON you should write your own (de)serializer for the date to incorporate this.

Comment: Well i dont want to influence parsing, i just vant to get validation error from the JSON...

Comment: As mentioned you cannot as you are validating the `Body` object **not** the JSON. So unless you are receiving that as a String and parse yourself and do that detection you cannot.

Comment: But can i save 1 JSON field to multiple values?

Comment: If you do manual mapping you can do everything you want. You cannot use Jackson anymore. But why is this difference so important to have in this case?

Comment: Its a NFR... but i guess we can convince the cilent that adding this is not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch manually those cases and give the corresponding error:

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Message> postController(@RequestBody Input input) 
{  
    //do your things
    ...
    
    if (date is blank) {//here you catch your cases
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(500)
                .body("Error: date value is blank");
    }
...
}
```

You should define 3 different cases (and 3 different error messages) for your Rest service.

Comment: But i dont have te underlying JSON. Unless i go full custom parsing for the object, i dont think i can access it. Spring magic in case of Localdate pases blank value into null.